# How to setup social login on nextcloud with mastodon as provider?

Tags: oauth-2.0, nextcloud, mastodon

I run a mastodon instance, and I want to set up a selfhosted nextcloud server that work for the same group of users by setting up social login.
nextcloud do have this plugin (app) that allow social login, which allows custom Oauth2.
Mastodon document indicate it support Oauth2.
I get an API key from the mastodon and put the information in nextcloud, but it doesn't work.  (the social login button shows up, but when I click the social login, I get 'page not found' error.)

[image]

the nextcloud server is deployed using AIO docker.  https://github.com/nextcloud/all-in-one

in the mastodon api, the only option I can change is the redirect url, I tried 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' and the nextcloud url, both gives the page not found error.

right now I'm stuck here,doesn't know what went wrong.

Q1,  Can any one help me diagnose what caused the problem?
I'm very new to web hosting, so even some hint on where I can find the real error code behind the 'page not found' would be helpful.

Q2, Am I going even the right direction?  I get the api key from a admin account from mastodon, but I'm not sure if that key can verify all the user in my instance.

Q3, is there an easy way to allow social login from all mastodon instances? each of them have different domain and I won't know them, but they are all in the fedi, so I guess there should be a protocol?

Thanks for the help!